# Why a minus in the equation of a paraxial plane wave?

Tags: optics, waves, conventions

paraxial plane wave = $\exp{(-jkz)}$ for waves propagating to the right

I can't figure out why it's not $\exp{(+jkz)}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I should clarify. This is within the context of Electrical Engineering. Mainly physical optics but I've seen similar notation in transmission lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of convention.  The complete wave function must describe a wave that propagates in the correct direction.  Any function of the form $f(kz - \omega t) = F(z - vt)$ describes a wave propagating to the right.  For a plane wave, that could be $\exp{(i(kz - \omega t))}$ or $\exp{ (-i(kz - \omega t))}$.  An author is free to choose whichever he or she wishes.  Of course, once chosen, the choice must be maintained.  The former is more common, I think, giving $\exp{(ikz)}$. Your author seems to have chosen differently.

Comment: The second convention is common in engineering, where the time dependence is often more important than the spatial. It is often tied to the use of $ j $ for the imaginary unit, so that $ i=-j $ is often a good heuristic for making sense of engineers.

Answer (score 0):

The wavevector does not always point to the direction of propagation. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector#Direction_of_the_wave_vector) from wikipedia to understand it better. The wavevector is basically parallel to the direction of propagation of the wave if the medium is isotropic (i.e uniform in every direction).

Comment: I think the cited article addresses a different issue, although the answer to the specific OP question might be buried in that article somewhere.